# SwiftUI be notified when all properties of an ObservableObject are updated

Tags: swift, mvvm, swiftui, xcode11, combine

I have an `ObservableObject`

```
class CurrentPosition: ObservableObject {
    @Published var northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
    @Published var southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2D()


    init(northEast: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(), southWest: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D()) {
        self.northEast = northEast
        self.southWest = southWest
    }

    func updateCoordinates(from mapView: MKMapView) {
        self.northEast = mapView.northEastCoordinate
        self.southWest = mapView.southWestCoordinate
    }
}
```

which I want to update from a MapView

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var weatherStations: [WeatherStation]
    @Binding var selectedWeatherStation: WeatherStation?

    @EnvironmentObject var currentPosition: CurrentPosition

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        let map = MKMapView()
        map.showsUserLocation = true
        map.delegate = context.coordinator
        return map
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        updateAnnotations(from: uiView)
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }


    final class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
        var control: MapView

        init(_ control: MapView) {
            self.control = control
        }

        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
            control.currentPosition.updateCoordinates(from: mapView)
        }

    }
}
```

and pass it to an `AppState` object

```
 MapView(weatherStations: $appState.appData.weatherStations,
                        selectedWeatherStation: $selectedWeatherStation).environmentObject(self.currentPosition)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical).onReceive(currentPosition.objectWillChange) { () in
                        self.appState.currentPosition = self.currentPosition
                }}
```

which in turn passes it to my API client

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var appData = AppData(weatherStations: [WeatherStation]())
    var currentPosition: CurrentPosition! {
        didSet {
            api.currentPosition = self.currentPosition
        }
    }
}
```

My issues is that it gets passed each time one of my `CurrentPosition` properties gets updated, meaning it first gets passed when `northEast` gets updated, than when `southWest` gets updated.

How can I pass it only one, when both finished updating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way is to fold it into one property using a secondary `struct`, like so:

```
struct MapCoordinateSpan {
  let northEast: CLLocationCoordinate2D
  let southWest: CLLocationCoordinate2D
}
```

and revise your `CurrentPosition` to look like this:

```
class CurrentPosition: ObservableObject {
    @Published var span: MapCoordinateSpan

    init(northEast: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(), southWest: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D()) {
        self.span = MapCoordinateSpan(northEast: northEast, southWest: southWest)
    }

    func updateCoordinates(from mapView: MKMapView) {
        self.span = MapCoordinateSpan(northEast: mapView.northEastCoordinate, southWest: mapView.southWestCoordinate)
    }
}
```

Then bind to the `span` property, and pluck out the coordinates from there.